# What is the time complexity of below code(recursive function) with respect to 'a'

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory, modulo

Time complexity of the recursive call

How 'a' value is decremented throughout the recursive call.

Is it  o(log a) or O(log log a)  or something else

```
int result(int a, int b)
{
 if( a %b == 0)
    return b;
 a = a % b;
 return result(b,a);
}
```

Comment: This is called the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanAlgorithm.html) and [this page](https://codility.com/media/train/10-Gcd.pdf) should hopefully answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's linear in the number of bits, i.e., `O(log(n)).`
Proof hint: show that after 2 iterations, `a` is divided by at least 2